# How to invoke method which takes an array as parameters in the Main method?

Tags: java, arrays

I am quite new to Java and in the process of learning Arrays. What I am trying to do here is to **subtract the largest with the second largest element** in an Array. I don't need any help with the process of the code (whether it is correct of not), as I believe I can figure this out myself once I have the Array printed in the console.

However, what I am having trouble with is invoking the `diff` method to work on the array I have given. The following is the code:

```
package com.Practice;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {

public static int diff(int[] a) {
    int largest = 0;
    int secLargest = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Array less than 2 elements!");
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] > a[j]) {
                a[i] = largest;
                largest = a[i];
            }
            if (a[i] < largest) {
                a[i] = secLargest;
            }
        }
    }
    return largest - secLargest;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr = {22, 3, 2, 55, 34, 56, 34, 123, 56, 34, 21, 5, 65};
    System.out.println("Original Array of numbers = " + Arrays.toString(arr));

// How do get the diff() method to work through the array given above down below?

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(diff(arr[]);
    }


}
```

}

I would appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Comment: just remove the `[]` after `arr`: `System.out.println(diff(arr));`

Comment: You almost have it. It should be:       `System.out.println(diff(arr));`

Comment: @CodeMatrix yes, plus it is missing a )

Comment: Thank you guys. This makes sense now. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the array without the `[]`, and you are missing a `)`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(diff(arr));
}
```

instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(diff(arr[]);
}
```